# check if JSON has child elements multiple times within a return

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to check the length (or if it even exists ) of JSON child elements before I loop through them.
my example has a note:

{const itHasChildren = item.child_items.length;}

the error I get with above is

src/Components/HeaderComponent/header.js
Line 60:29:  'childItem' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
  return (
    <nav >
    
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
        {menus &&
          menus.map((item) => (
          
              <li className="nav-item active" key={item.ID}>
              
                  <Link >{item.title} </Link>


     // I NEED TO CHECK THE LENGTH  OR IF child_items EXISTS 
     //  HERE SO I CAN DECIDE WHETHER TO DISPLAY THIS DIV OR NOT

              {item.child_items.map((childItem).length)}

              <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" >

              {item.child_items &&
                item.child_items.map((childItem) => (
            
                      <Link >{childItem.title} </Link>
                    
                      ))}
                  </div>
            </li>
           
          ))}
      </ul>
 </nav>
  );
```

Comment: This will give a syntax error since is jsx code `{item.child_items && item.child_items.map((childItem) => ( <div /> ))}` and must run inside a Component or Fragment `<></>`

Comment: could you show me an example of how my code would work with a fragment, I added them and still got syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the syntax and condition I was looking for

```
<li 
            className={
                item.child_items
                  ? "nav-item dropdown"
                  : "nav-item  "
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your code a bit so it should work. Just the first element inside the map needs the `key` and according to your data it could be the index position in the array

```js
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <button
        className="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          {(menus || []).map((item, ix) => (
            <li key={ix} className="nav-item active">
              <Link
                className="nav-link"
                to={{
                  pathname: item.slug,
                  state: {
                    pageId: item.slug
                  }
                }}
              >
                {item.title}
              </Link>

              {(item.child_items || []).map((childItem, ix) => (
                <div key={ix} className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <Link
                    className="dropdown-item"
                    to={{
                      pathname: childItem.slug,
                      state: {
                        pageId: childItem.slug
                      }
                    }}
                  >
                    {childItem.title}
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
```

Comment: thanks for helping.. that didnt work.. I still get the index error.. also, there is no conditonal statements on the first li and link classes

Comment: I figured out the Key error, the drop down div needs to be outside the child_items.map...  but again, like the first list item and Link, I only want to display it if there are child items.  I need to create something I can use 3 times, if child_items display this, else display that

Comment: So you need test child_items.length

Comment: how would that look Uke, as soon as I try to display {item.child_items.length}   I get     errors Uncaught TypeError: item.child_items is undefined and SyntaxError: /Users/justin/Desktop/react-wordpress-headless/src/Components/HeaderComponent/header.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (45:8)